# Getting doNotTrack setting in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, do-not-track

According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/do-not-track), support for `navigator.doNotTrack` ***used*** to be in Safari, but was dropped in version 12.1

Was it superseded by anything? Is there a new / better way to get a user's `doNotTrack` setting? I'm building a request for an ad server and want to ensure that I send the appropriate value here. On all other browsers I have this working fine.

Comment: There is no such thing as "do not track" in Safari. That's what `caniuse` is saying with 'dropped in version 12.1'

Comment: So is the appropriate assumption that you're always allowed to track users in Safari?